# Access Python class `__dict__` within class initializer?

Tags: python, class, inheritance, reflection, initialization

How can I access a class's `__dict__` within its own "class initializer" (class definition) code? Failing that, how can I access the class's-to-be-defined attributes as strings (so that one can generate their names, and set their values, programmatically)

```
class A:  # from a library by a stubborn maintainer
  def __init__ (self):
    self.hello = "Hello"
    # + some huge misguided crap that I do not control
  def f1 (self):
    self.f2 ()
  def f2 (self):
    print self.hello

class B:
  f1 = A.__dict__ ['f1'] # works
  # how to loop over 2..10 and set B.f$i <- A.f$i ?
  # this doesn't work:
  #B.__dict__ ['f2'] = A.__dict__ ['f2']  # B not yet defined
  def __init__ (self):
    #self.hello = A ().hello  # the actual code has to be copied manually
    # misguided crap removed

a = B ()
a.f2()
```

It would be good to also not copy/paste the self.hello initialization just to bypass the misguided stuff, but I don't think that can be helped easily short of refactoring tools.

Comment: How about sublclassing A?

Comment: And run A's initializer? Is there a way to avoid it? Still, I'd like to pick and choose methods. If there are errors, I can decide whether to add more methods or not

Comment: You could override the methods you don't like in your subclass, and never call `super`. Perhaps I don't understand the question well enough.

Comment: A has hundreds of methods. It is a conflation of many concepts. I want to pick and choose and see what (and if) it works. I'll resort to cut/paste/modify where needed. But good point about not calling super (though, I still need some code from super, which has to be copy/pasted)

Comment: Oh I see. This sounds like a good use case for some metaclass magic... One sec.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, you can't really do that while the class is being defined. In other words, you can't access a class's`__dict__`in its own definition because the results of executing the definition will become the dictionary's content (that's why the class name hasn't been bound to anything yet). Probably the simplest workaround for this would be to give your class a `__metaclass__`.

A metaclass is the class-of-a-class, so instances of them are classes (hence the name). For simplicity I've put the definition of one for`B`inside of it, since its use and scope will be limited to that class (this, however, can't be done in Python 3).

The code in`__metaclass__.__new__()`is only executed when instance of *it* are created, namely during class`B`'s definition, not whenever instances of class`B`are created, so the overhead of copying all the methods is will incurred only when that happens -- usually once. Note that because class methods are also descriptor objects, it's necessary to call the`__get__`method of each one in order to get the proper value to bind them to the another class object. See the section titled [*Descriptor HowTo Guide*](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html?highlight=descriptor#descriptor-howto-guide) by Raymond Hettinger in the documentation for more details.

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.hello = "Hello"
        # + some huge misguided crap that I do not control
    def f1(self):
        self.f2()
    def f2(self):
        print self.hello

class B(object):
    class __metaclass__(type):
        A_METHODS = ['f{}'.format(i) for i in xrange(1, 11)] # 'f1'...'f10'

        def __new__(mcls, classname, bases, classdict):
            classobj = type.__new__(mcls, classname, bases, classdict)
            classobj.hello = A().hello
            for fn in mcls.A_METHODS:
                if fn in A.__dict__:
                    setattr(classobj, fn, A.__dict__[fn].__get__(classobj, A))
            return classobj

    def __init__(self):
        pass

a = B()
a.f2()  # --> Hello
```

Comment: Interesting take, solves original *problem* though it doesn't technically answer the original *question*. I may ultimately go that route, thanks. Though I'm still curious about the original syntax / scoping question.

Comment: I meant within **the class initializer** (the stuff that follows `class B` before any method), not within the **instance __init__** which must execute everytime an instance is created. How can I amend my question to make that more clear?

Comment: You can't access `B.__dict__` in the class definition because `B` (and its `__dict__`) won't exist until the code in its definition has finished executing.

Comment: Yeah. Hence the *original question* :) And "failing that" how can I access class attributes programmatically as strings etc...

Comment: Sure, add that -- though apparently there is a non-portable, probably unstable way to do it as per the other answer. I wouldn't go with either -- I would update the class def after defining it. I was curious about Py's meta-/reflection capabilities, so that's why I've asked

Comment: You can access class attributes as strings using the form `getattr(class, attrname)`.

Comment: What I'm looking for here is `setattr (B, "f1", ...)`, but again that won't work within "class definition" code (since B is undefined). Neither would `getattr (B, ...)`, right?

Comment: Tested and works. And the answer to the original Q seems to be 'no (not directly)'

Answer (score 1):

There may be a better approach entirely (such as forking the class A and removing the misguided code, or having each B instance hold or share an A instance, or modifying `B.__dict__` after the definition of `B` is complete).

That said, you could replace:

```
B.__dict__ ['f2'] = A.__dict__ ['f2']  # B not yet defined
```

with:

```
locals()['f2'] = A.__dict__ ['f2']
```

*This is not guaranteed to work* because you aren't allowed to modify `locals()`, but it does appear to work in CPython 2.7.5 at least:

```
class Foo:
    a = locals()
    locals()['b'] = 0

print Foo.a is Foo.__dict__, Foo.b
```

outputs `True 0`. Interestingly, it outputs `False 0` if `Foo` inherits from `object`, which indicates the difficult water I'm in.

Of course this is a horrible abuse of implementation-specific behaviour, is not recommended, will probably go wrong somewhere down the line, etc :-)

Comment: Yeah, I wrote `f1 = A.__dict__ ['f1']`to demonstrate my knowledge of that route :) Suppose I want to access B's attributes in bulk, programmatically, as strings (read 1st paragraph of question). Suppose I want to copy methods (or attributes) based on their names.

Comment: @dan3: then maybe the "alternatively" will work. It depends whether you need the attributes to have already been set in the class code, for instance if you need to use the value `f2` on the line after your commented-out line, then delaying the `__dict__` manipulation won't help you.

Comment: @dan3: yeah, I realised that too (that's why I changed my example in my last comment, it was a bad one...)

Comment: Oh I've thought about modifying B after definition (which of course works) but that doesn't answer the original Q (accessing B's attributes as strings within the class initializer). Perhaps it is impossible... I'll upvote anyway.